# change ngModel value with checkbox

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

good day .. I have this code and I need to send the role..but when I select the checkbox the ngModel changes to True or False and it is what is sent to the DB..How can I solve it?

```
<mdl-checkbox class="mdl-textfield--full-width" *ngFor="let role of roles; let i = index"
[(ngModel)]="user.roles[i] " name="ckb{{i}}">
{{role.name}}
</mdl-checkbox>
```

Comment: What is `roles`? Is a role an object, or just a string?

Comment: is an object..{ "id": 3, "name": "ROLE_USER" } for exmple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can set user roles in `change` event? Like `(change)="userRoles[i] = role"` A sample plunkr using Angular only:

https://plnkr.co/edit/erIQNgk6u1JxOc6zCoHW?p=preview

Comment: thank you very much you saved me just needed that '='

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with only template. But it might be that you are overwriting the data if you are sending user, since you are using `[(ngModel)]="user.roles[i]"` on your checkbox, you are altering that value by clicking on the checkbox. You can create an item on the roles array by doing `role.isChecked`. Then you can store the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest altering your object.

```
public class Role {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    enabled: boolean;
}

<mdl-checkbox class="mdl-textfield--full-width" *ngFor="let role of roles; let i = index" [(ngModel)]="user.roles[i].Enabled" name="ckb{{i}}">
    {{role.name}}
</mdl-checkbox>
```

Comment: I have some problems I think it's because 'roles' is an object inside a model.ts called users import                                                                  {Role} from '../roles/role.model';

export class User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
  lastNameF: string;
  lastNameM: string;
  phone: string;
  officePhone: string;
  roles: Role[];
}

Comment: When you post your model, put your Enabled Roles on the User.